# Omission of elision in Aeneis I.405?

Tags: classical-latin, poetry, elision, scansion, aeneis

I ran into this hexameter verse by Vergilius when researching [for an answer to another question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1505/79):

> *et vera incessu patuit dea. Ille ubi matrem*
>   (Aeneis I.405)

The only way I can scan that verse is to leave a hiatus between *dea* and *ille*.
Is this scansion correct?
Is elision still possible across punctuation, or should it always be omitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a hiatus because it's located at the principle caesura:

> et vera | inces|su patu|it dea. || Ille ubi | matrem

In fact, Lodge [specifically references](https://books.google.com/books?id=H5UZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA473#v=onepage&q&f=false) this line in the section on hiatus, as I'm sure do a few others.

Note that hiatus isn't impossible anywhere, but it's common specifically here. The grammars will typically say "most" or "usually", and I'm sure you can find exceptions.

Comment: Thank you! And welcome back to the site; I haven't seen you for a while.

Comment: This isn't at a normal caesura point, which may come after IIa, IIIa, or IVa, but after IVb2. I usually interpret this specific instance as Vergilius saying rather forcefully that "the current sentence ends right here".