# Fifth spondee in Aeneis I.690

Tags: classical-latin, poetry, vergilius, scansion, aeneis

I ran into this hexameter verse by Vergilius when researching [for an answer to another question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1505/79):

> *exuit, et gressu gaudens incedit Iuli.*
>   (Aeneis I.690)

The only way I seem to able to scan this line is by taking the fifth foot to be spondee.
In my experience this is very rare, so I am in doubt.
Wikipedia tells me that spondee in the fifth foot was almost never used by Roman poets, and rarely (5 %) by Homeros.

Is my scansion correct?
Should I treat this as a highly exceptional case, or something to be expected from Vergilius?

It just occurred to me, after posting the question, that perhaps *Iuli* could have three syllables: *Ĭ-ū-lī*.
This would save the dactyl but it sounds otherwise weird.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Iulus is always trisyllabic.

Comment: @TKR, I didn't know that. I took considerable amount of time for that option to cross my mind, and I still found it unlikely. If you can find support for three syllables (elsewhere in the epic, perhaps), that would make a good answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name Ĭūlus is trisyllabic. It's listed as such in dictionaries, e.g. [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3DIulus2), and there's ample metrical evidence for this, though much of it is indirect.

A [search](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%5BVerg%3AA%5D+%23iul) for forms of Iūlus in the Aeneid finds that it never occurs at the beginning of a line -- in fact, it's almost always line-final, as in the line you quote. This itself is suspicious since if the name was Jūl-, beginning with a consonant, there would be no reason for it not to begin a line. Further, if you look at the final syllables of the words that precede these line-final forms of Iūlus, they always contain short vowels (like the *-dit* of *incedit* in your line). This is because they're the second syllables of dactyls. If they were the second syllables of spondees, this would be an odd coincidence.

Finally, I've found one case where the scansion seems unambiguously trisyllabic, namely a line from Propertius, *Elegies* 4.1a.48:

> felix terra tuos cepit, Iule, deos.

This is the second line of an elegiac couplet, and the second half of such a line is always dactylic, which means the last two-and-a-half feet must be *cepit I|ule de|os*.

The reason this sounds weird to you is maybe the association with the name *Iūlius*, in which the *I* is consonantal.

Comment: Many thanks! It added to my confusion that in Finnish Iulus is often called "Julus". It's also good to know that *Iulius* is different from *Iulus* in that respect.

Comment: Let me add that the name is "Julus" (with a consonantal J) also in the metric Finnish translation by Alpo Rönty. I just checked my copy. I found no comment about changing the name.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta♦: I've always pronounced it *Julus* in my head as well, but perhaps that pronunciation, and the ensuing spelling with a j, is just a postclassical error?

Comment: @Cerberus, could be. And one could insist on using the consonantal pronunciation at the cost or producing spondees, although I don't find it very convincing.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta♦: Another thought: could it be that *Iulus* is entirely unrelated to *Iulius*, the former Trojan, the latter Roman, only conexed artificially by Virgil for obvious reasons?

Comment: @Cerberus, an excellent question which should be asked separately. I don't think that should be buried in a comment thread.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta♦: Done! I even found some information in Pauly, but I didn't want to overdocument my question.